# Issue compiling IONIC app with React on modern Android devices using Phonegap-nfc plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, nfc, capacitor, phonegap

I'm developing a mobile application using **IONIC 6** with **React**and **Typescript** with **Capacitor 5.0** on **Windows 10** with **Java-17**. The application uses the **Phonegap-nfc** plugin for **NFC** communication. The app **works** fine on older Android devices (**Android 8.0**), but when I try to compile it on newer Android devices (**Android 12**), it **doesn't work** and exit inmediatly.

I have tried installing plugins for both Capacitor and Cordova, but the problem persists. When I don't have the Phonegap-nfc plugin installed, the app works without issues, but when I install it, the error occurs.

I have looked at the official documentation and other pages, but I haven't found a solution. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

1. How can I fix the problem that occurs when compiling the app on newer Android devices?
2. Is it possible that the Phonegap-nfc plugin is not compatible with newer Android devices?
3. Is there an alternative solution I can use to communicate with NFC on newer Android devices?
4. Is there any special configuration I need to be aware of when compiling the app for newer Android devices?
5. Is there any specific error message I can provide to help troubleshoot the issue?

With phonegap-nfc plugin this is my component: [NFC Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P70mF.png)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/478

and

https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/issues/465

But it seems this plugin is not maintained any more (though there are forks with fixes applied)

There was a change in Android 12 that affected an old way of using NFC via Intents. When using an Intent on Android 12 you have to specify it's mutability (NFC needs mutable Intents) See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#pending-intent-mutability So you probably need an updated Plugin, hopefully one that uses a newer and better way of using NFC without Intents

There is a fix linked to the issue to specify the mutability of the Intent.

You don't specify how you use the plugin, but it does offer `readerMode` (https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcreadermode) which does not use Intents and this is not affected by the change in Android 12

Though there is another change in Android 12L that the plugin does not handle properly (even with `readerMode`) and can sometimes cause a crash due to a new Security Exception that can be thrown.

Comment: Now, What can I do?

Comment: Use the `readerMode` methods in the current plugin or build and use the fork with the fix or apply the fix yourself to the plugin and build it. Or chase the plugin owner to accept the fix and re-release the plugin.

Comment: I don't know any android developing, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Use the `readerMode` methods then as that is just using the same language you are already using.

Answer (score 0):

I have this fixed --
Use https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/pull/477/files

and make changes to the Nfcplugin.java file within your project.

for Cordova remove the android platform and add it again, so it can add these file changes to the android files.

This fixed it for me.
I'm using SDK 33.0.3, Cordova 12